# How to extract the "real frames" without rely on fps?

Tags: ffmpeg

I noticed if I extract frames with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i sample_nosound.mp4 $filename%03d.jpg
```

It will extract depends on fps by default. `ffmpeg -i` shows this video has 6 fps, so it extracted 1630 jpg frame files, which 1630/6 = 271.6 seconds equivalent to the 4:32 total video duration.

But 1630 jpg frames total size is 13 MB:

```
$ du -h extracted_jpg_folder
13M      extracted_jpg_folder
```

, while the file size of the mp4 is 1.8 MB, far  lower than the total frames size:

```
$ ls -la sample_nosound.mp4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xiaobai xiaobai 1814889 Feb  13 15:42 'sample_nosound.mp4'
```

That means ffmpeg extract frames by referring fps info.

Therefore my question is, **how to make ffmpeg extract frames by "real frames" without rely on fps ?**

I expect I can get total frames size which almost equivalent with the mp4 files size.

I don't expect exact match file size, since mp4 may contains some metadata.

Comment: Video in MP4 typically uses [interframe](http://www.canon.com.hk/cpx/en/technical/va_EOS_Movie_Compression_Options_All_I_and_IPB.html) compression, so your expectation is mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

You don't quite understand how this works.
h.264 doesn't save single images, but much rather one image, than f.e. 4 estimations what should come after.

For example:
Imagine a ball rolling from left to right, you could noe either store 30 frames of the ball rolling, or you store 1 frame of the ball in the beginning and one in the end, and when you play the video, just take the first image, and copy the ball a bit to the right.

This means, that I Frame compression can be smaller, than single frames.

Comment: Yes, now I understand why download some streaming in half way is not possible to recover without original image.

Comment: @林果皞 Well; if I understand you correctly, Interframes aren't the problem with this. You don't just have one "Main" frame and the rest are generated. It's more like One "Mainframe" and then 4 generated ones. Not being able to download just the half is another problem

Comment: I think I already understand with `Intra-frames` info in this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500672/64403 ,  but I get confuse after read your comment about "Mainframe" and "Main" frame.

Comment: "Mainframe" and "Main" Frame are the same, my bad.